# Python3 except ValueError: if/else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, try-except

I want to make a try/except to ensure that the inputted value is a float variable. However i want to make an exception if the inputted value is 'g' then i want to redefine the variable to '9.8' instead of telling me that it must be a number. Below is my try but there seems to be a problem with it.
PS ignore my mistake of printing "must be an integer"

[image]

Comment: ... I don't see any code?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, can you see the code now?

Comment: try a tabstop of 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example won't work because if `ValueError` actually occured, the variable `a` doesn't exist. Python interpreter tried to create variable `a` but it could not be done so it raised an error. Therefore you cannot use `a` inside the `except` block.

You should first save `input("A:")` to a variable and test if it's value is `"g"`. If it is, you set it to "9.8". Next step would be to transform this variable to a float.

All this should be done inside the `try` block.